# Are there endoscopic technologies for blood vessels?

Tags: hematology

Endoscopic procedures are used to look inside cavities like intestine, esophagus etc. Is it being used to look inside blood vessels?

Comment: there are endovascular procedures that we use for looking at vascular anatomy and clots/blockages within blood vessels - these are surgical procedures that are typically performed by Vascular Surgeons, but Cardiologists also do similar procedures for defining the coronary vasculature, and interventional radiologists also perform vasculature procedures as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interventional_radiology#Vascular

Answer (score 3):

Blood is hard to see through, so visualization with a camera isn't used (to my knowledge). However, [Intravascular ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravascular_ultrasound) can be used, though it is expensive and not all that common. Instead, [angiography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angiography) is usually used, by filling the vessels with a radio-opaque dye

There are also many techniques used to treat vascular conditions, like balloons/stents to open and keep open blocked or partially blocked vessels, or to repair valves. You can read more about [Interventional cardiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interventional_cardiology) or [minimally invasive procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimally_invasive_procedures).

Answer (score 0):

Another work [1] that might be interesting to look at is the one titled as "[Interactive Volume Segmentation with Threshold Field Painting](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2984537)". The work addresses the problem of volume segmentation mainly for *blood vessels* inside the brain. It is a [Human-Computer Interaction (HCI)](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/human-computer-interaction) research, however, the authors used several procedures and devices to work with. Might be interesting to answer your question.

Finally, and most importantly, it might be important to you look [2] at a paper called "[3D Reconstruction with Low Resolution, Small Baseline and High Radial Distortion Stereo Images](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2967435)". In this paper, the authors analyze and compare approaches for 3D reconstruction from low-resolution (`250 x 250`), high radial distortion stereo images, which are acquired with a small baseline.

[1] Takeo Igarashi, Naoyuki Shono, Taichi Kin, and Toki Saito. 2016. Interactive Volume Segmentation with Threshold Field Painting. In Proceedings of the 29th Annual Symposium on User Interface Software and Technology (UIST '16). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 403-413. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/2984511.2984537

[2] Tiago Dias, Helder Araujo, and Pedro Miraldo. 2016. 3D Reconstruction with Low Resolution, Small Baseline and High Radial Distortion Stereo Images. In Proceedings of the 10th International Conference on Distributed Smart Camera (ICDSC '16). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 98-103. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/2967413.2967435